# addApi creates it but returns error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am adding new api  to wso2 as described [in the wso2 Publisher APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+APIs)

The query is the following

```
http://testapiaddress:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag?action=addAPI&name=PhoneVerification&context=/phoneverify&version=1.0&visibility=public&thumbUrl=&description=Verify a phone number&tags=phone,mobile,multimedia&endpointType=nonsecured&tiersCollection=Gold,Bronze&http_checked=http&https_checked=https&uriTemplate-0=/*&default_version_checked=default_version&bizOwner=xx&bizOwnerMail=xx@ee.com&techOwner=xx&techOwnerMail=ggg@ww.com"&endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://myaccountapi.dev.payoneer.com","config":null},"endpoint_type":"address"}&swagger={"paths" : {"/CheckPhoneNumber?PhoneNumber={number}" : {"get" : {"parameters" : [{"description" : "phone number", "name" : "number", "allowMultiple" : false, "type" : "string", "required" : true, "in" : "path"}], "responses" : {"200" : {}}, "x-auth-type" : "Application%20%26%20Application%20User", "x-throttling-tier" : "Unlimited"}}, "/test" : {}, "/" : {}}, "swagger" : "2.0", "info" : {"title" : "WeatherAPI", "version" : "1.0.0"}}
```

I can see that the api **was created** in publisher portal but i get error as a response

```
{"error" : false}
```

Their response is very generic, but maybe someone has idea why i get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error. It says that there is no error.
If there is an error response will be like below:

```
{"error" : true, "description":"error description"}
```